# EF Core does not return more than 3 child objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a folder structure in my application, where I recursively want to retrieve all children below a parent.

```
//Pseudocode
Context.Files.Include(p => p.Children);
```

In cases where my parent has 3 children, I retrieve an `IEnumerable<Files>` of Parent.Children.Children.Children.. However, when I have more than 3 children, It only returns the first child object, i.e. File.Children

The child property is written as follows in my object class:

```
public virtual ICollection<Files> Children { get; set; }
```

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: The code you provided is basic and does't help much, if i were to assume that you're making the right query to the database then the problem is probably in how are you're associating the childeren with the parent in the database, and this is just a guess.

Comment: It is also very basic, linq is taking care of the query for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `.Include` will not generate recursive SQL. It simply connects the foreign relation set for Children to your Files, which should be one nesting deep.

If you were to pull the entire set of Files, with `.Include` children, then what you will have is a set of edge pieces. In order to turn a set of edge pieces into a connected graph, you will need to manually compose that in your code.

Create a method which will iterate through each Files object, and if it is related to a Children set, then connect it into there. This will create your object graph and allow you to traverse in the manner you expect.

For added performance, create a top down GUID column for linking so that you can pull only the file tree you are interested in.

If you know the exact depth you are interested in, then you can manually compose the include. Alternatively, you could create a custom Expression Builder to do this dynamically but that is beyond the scope of this answer.

```
Context.Files.Include(
    p => p.Children.Select( 
        pc => pc.Children.Select( 
            pcc => pcc.Children
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I figured that may be an issue. However, I guess it shouldn't be able to fetch a child 2 levels down as i describe, right?

Comment: That is correct. You would need to issue two different requests, gather both from the first request, or assign a GUID to the object graph in a column in your database in order to grab both up front.

Comment: But even so, it is capable of fetching items 2 levels down, just not 3.

Comment: If you were to use a projection, you can go as far down as you want. However, that isn't possible simply using `.Include(f => f.Children)`. I will edit in a 3 level deep example.

Comment: I get what you say! But what makes me wonder is, that according to your explanation I should only be able to get the first child regardless. That is however not the case, I can retrieve a children 3 levels down, but if i query a parent with 4 children it only gives me the first child.

Comment: That is more than likely due to eager loading. If the object is loaded from your original query, and is present in the result set, then the object relation may exist. However, if the fourth child level down is not part of the query set, then it will not be available.

Comment: @JeppeChristensen if you're requesting all the hierarchy all the time wouldn't a stored procedure fit the requirements?

Comment: That is a valid idea, I may look into that! Thank you for the input.

Comment: As HMZ suggests, a stored procedure would also be a good idea here, as code executing on the database server is far more efficient than using bandwidth for analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution.

```
private static async Task<IReadOnlyList<File>> GetRootFilesAndChildren(IQueryable<File> source, int levels = 3)
{
    var dataSource = source.Where(x => x.ParentFileId == null); //root files

    if (levels == 0)
        return await dataSource.ToListAsync();

    var dataSourceIncludable = dataSource.Include(x => x.Children);
    for (var i = 1; i < levels; i++)
        dataSourceIncludable = dataSourceIncludable.ThenInclude(x => x.Children);

    var files = await dataSourceIncludable.ToListAsync();
    return files;
}
```

**EDIT** I forgot to include the models and configuration.

```
public class File
{
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentFileId { get; set; }
    public File ParentFile { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<File> Children { get; set; }
}
```

The DbContext for SQLite.

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=demo.db");

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<File>(b =>
        {
            b.ToTable("Files");

            b.HasMany(x => x.Children)
                .WithOne(x => x.ParentFile)
                .IsRequired(false);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point with regards to ThenInclude as OP does indicate the user of EF Core.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your scenario, there are multiple ways to accomplish what you want.

---

The simplest way is to just load all entities (EF Core will do the relationship fixup for you) and then just work from the parent you actually care about:

```cs
public class File
{
    public int FileId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int ParentFolderId {get; set;}

    public Folder ParentFolder {get; set;}

    public string Path => ParentFolder?.Path + "/" + Name;
}

public class Folder
{
    public int FolderId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int ParentFolderId {get; set;}
    
    public Folder ParentFolder {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Folder> SubFolders {get; set;} = new HashSet<Folder>();
    public ICollection<Files> Files {get; set;} = new HashSet<File>();

    public string Path => ParentFolder?.Path + "/" + Name;
}

context.Files.Load();
context.Folders.Load();

var rootFolderICareAbout = context.Folders.Local.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Path == "/My/Folder/Path");
```

---

Here is another way, that works with a single model class:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class FileOrFolder
    {
        public int FileOrFolderId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsFolder { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }

        public FileOrFolder Parent { get; set; }
        public ICollection<FileOrFolder> Children { get; set; } = new HashSet<FileOrFolder>();

        public bool HasAncestor(FileOrFolder parent) => Parent == parent || (Parent?.HasAncestor(parent) ?? false);
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<FileOrFolder> FileOrFolders { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=.\MSSQL14;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=So62854494")
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<FileOrFolder>(
                entity =>
                {
                    entity.HasOne(f => f.Parent)
                        .WithMany(f => f.Children)
                        .HasForeignKey(f => f.ParentId);

                    entity.HasData(
                        new FileOrFolder {FileOrFolderId = 1, Name = "RootFolder", IsFolder = true, ParentId = null},
                        new FileOrFolder {FileOrFolderId = 2, Name = "RootFile1", IsFolder = false, ParentId = 1},
                        new FileOrFolder {FileOrFolderId = 3, Name = "RootFile2", IsFolder = false, ParentId = 1},
                        new FileOrFolder {FileOrFolderId = 4, Name = "SubFolder", IsFolder = true, ParentId = 1},
                        new FileOrFolder {FileOrFolderId = 5, Name = "SubFile1", IsFolder = false, ParentId = 4},
                        new FileOrFolder {FileOrFolderId = 6, Name = "SubFile2", IsFolder = false, ParentId = 4});
                });
        }
    }
    
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using var context = new Context();
            
            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var rootFolder = context.FileOrFolders.Single(f => f.ParentId == null);

            var subFilesOrFolders = context.FileOrFolders
                .Include(f => f.Parent)
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Where(f => f.HasAncestor(rootFolder))
                .ToList();
            
            Debug.Assert(subFilesOrFolders.Count == 5);
            Debug.Assert(subFilesOrFolders.First(f => f.IsFolder).Name == "SubFolder");
            Debug.Assert(subFilesOrFolders.First(f => f.IsFolder).Children.Count == 2);
        }
    }
}
```

---

These are quick and simple solutions. For better performance, you need to issue hierarchical queries.